# How to flip a Path element horizontally

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have this `<Path>` element in a xaml file. I would like to create a copy and flip it horizontally so that the shape will point in the other direction. The `<Path>` has a really long `Data` field so I was wondering if there was a way to flip one of the  elements instead of just eyeballing the element and manually making it appear the same shape and size.

I looked into flipping the image programatically using `RenderTransform` and `ScaleTransform`, but I am afraid it might hinder the performance of the application especially during a window resize.

References: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/graphics-multimedia/transforms-overview

> Is there a protocol or way I can translate the `Path` element's `Data`
>   field into its **horizontally** flipped opposite in a way that wonder hurt
>   the performance of the application?

Comment: You can also explicitly assign a PathGeometry to the Data property, and set the PathGeometry's Transform property.

Comment: @Clemens would it be much different than the accepted answer? In terms of performance would it be the same?

Comment: There wouldn't be any noticable difference. I've just mentioned it in case you couldn't set RenderTransform for some reason. E.g. because it's already used for some other purpose. Or you later decide to stretch the Path, but don't want to also stretch its stroke.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to mirror the shape you might want to try this:

```
<Path data= "...">
  <Path.RenderTransform>
     <ScaleTransform ScaleX="-1.0"/>
  </Path.RenderTransform>
</Path>
```

This doesn't really hurt the performance, since all rendered elements are transformed at some point anyway.

Comment: And it's worth adding that to *any* visual element in WPF can have a RenderTransform.